# Where on the Kardashev scale would the First ones from the space odyssey series be placed?

Tags: arthur-c-clarke

I was just wondering where people thought the first ones depicted as being the creators of the monoliths featured in such masterpieces as 2001 , 2010 ,2061 and 3001 by Arthur C Clarke would be placed on the Kardashev scale.
Personally I think its type 4 as they have been implied to be able to control entire universes as hinted at by this interview between Kubrick and Playboy magazine http://dpk.io/kubrick

Comment: This seems very speculative

Comment: Any answer will depend on whether the Kadashev scale is meant to demarcate actions or just capabilities.  Von Neumann machines capable of surrounding a Jupiter-sized mass and causing it to initiate fusion suggests Kardashev 3 *capability*, but there's no evidence that monoliths or their makers are out smothering galaxies.

Comment: The answer will also depend on which period of the creators' history is being examined.  The monoliths are leftovers from an earlier stage of the creators' existence, when the creators still used physical tools.

Comment: Yes but the Jupiter monolith opened up a star gate which is definitely more advanced than what a type 3 could do.